# Reflection of a circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Someone submitted this problem to me:
[image: Problem description]

A physicist would argue that light is a wave and that it passes anyway.
However here we are dealing with a problem of pure geometry.
My first instinct was to try and find a way that it does follow some kind of easy rule, but it did not work.
My second attempt was to try and find a pattern when solving analytically the problem for low values of N reflections. Here is the Desmos simulation of my attempt: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k9cuxxn4x5
It is very basic geometry with tangent calculation (calculation of lines intercepting a circle, calculation of tangent and calculation of reflexions), and the analytic geometry becomes complicated for large N, so I assume there is an easy way that I completely missed.
In this Desmos sheet I called a the distance between the top of the circle and the mirror.

Comment: For one, I am pretty certain that the circle ought to be tangent to the incident beam. Also, if the beam ever passes the midway point of the circle, then it will come put on the other side. I am also _pretty_ certain that there is a point at which the light beam doesn't come out on either side (it just comes closer and closer to the midway point, never passing it and never turning back), and if the circle is closer than that, the beam comes back, and if the circle is further away than that, then the ray gets through. If that's the case, there won't be a minimal distance.

Comment: Also, there is a question of similar nature [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489525/for-what-measures-of-%e2%88%a0a-are-there-infinitely-many-intersections). It's possible that your problem is just as hard to solve, but it's also possible that your setup being about the distance between the circles (you might as well have two circles instead of a circle and a straight wall) rather than the angle of the beam makes it easier. I do not know.

Comment: "I am pretty certain that the circle ought to be tangent to the incident beam" Yes it is. The question link is similar by reflection of the problem (turning a mirror into another circle), but the solution provided is numerical and not analytical

Answer (score -1):

Ray component on x-axis is *always to the right*.

When gap is zero, angles of incidence are progressively diminishing to converge towards zero  *monotonously.* Reflected rays are confined to the left of arbelos area and undergo infinitely many bounces but never leave the zero gap tangency point.

A positive gap allows a positive rightward horizontal component by laws of reflection and the rays converge before diverging. Reflected angles at fist reduce and then increase. That is, rays eventually escape. A rough typical ray-trace is sketched having forward components.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you said but that does not solve the question, does it?

Comment: What is the proof of the first sentence?

Comment: Apologies, revised what I did not exactly want to say..

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you said but that does not solve the problem either. We are look for the minimal distance between the circle and the mirror. What you wrote is correct but does not add information to my desmos model, does it? @Narasimham

Comment: I don't see why this isn't an acceptable answer. Whatever the gap $> 0$ the ray will go through, so it's more a *physics* question, where the answer is something near the Planck length ($1.6\cdot 10^{-35} m$). No?